# Ionic keyboard.isVisible property does not control element visibility properly

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic5, ionic-keyboard

After many years of reading your answers I have my first question.

**SITUATION**

In Ionic Angular (v5.3.1) mobile application I'm trying to do simple task - hide element when keyboard opens.
Principle is simple:

- I click on text-box
- Event `keyboardWillShow` happens
- Phone keyboard shows up
- Element hides (`*ngIf="keyboard.isVisible"`)

**THE PROBLEM**

When keyboard opens - element is still visible. Even if event `keyboardWillShow` was executed. but - when I click on text-box again - element become hidden, as I needed at the beginning.

**SAMPLE CODE**

***tab1.page.html***

```
<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <ion-textarea placeholder="This is placeholder"></ion-textarea>
  <div *ngIf="keyboard.isVisible">
    Please click on tech area and keyboar will open
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

***tab1.page..ts***

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})
export class Tab1Page {

  constructor(
    public keyboard: Keyboard
  ) {}

}
```

Comment: maybe angular's change detection didnt pick up the change of keyboard's visibility. Try to manually detect change or use a separate bool flag in ngIf

Comment: I have the same issue.